# Changing setPreferredSize away from base 0

Tags: camera, screen, scene, stage

I have a program using `setPreferredSize(1500, 900)`, which I assume means the "camera" displays pixels 0 to 1500, and 0 to 900. I am aiming to essentially make the x value change to 1500 to 3000, leaving everything drawn behind in 0-1500 and being able to draw anew in 1500 - 3000. Any suggestions? I don't believe this should be that difficult, but I am not all that experienced yet. Thanks in advance!